# Flow Blockchain - Single Smart Contract to manage multiple template-based Smart Contracts

Tags: onflow-cadence

My goal is to manage different smart contracts (which are created from the same template contract, just replaced name, paths,etc) with a single, sort of, Registry Smart Contract. Only people who have admin resource of Registry contract is able to call admin-related functions in child's smart contracts (Or any other solution, just want a single source of management). The template smart contract is ready, the only challenge now it to understand (if it's even possible) how to manage those contracts from a main smart contract